# Textview height not update [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift

I having this issue when the device is with ios14. The text view height is not updated. Below is my code:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

    var frame = textView.frame
    print("before::\(textView.frame.size.height)")
    frame.size.height = size.height

    textView.frame = frame
    print("after::\(textView.frame.size.height)")
    
    
    self.messageInputContainerView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

}

inputTextView is the textview that i added as a subview in messageInputContainerView.
The print out before and after height is different however the ui is not update for device with ios14 only.

Comment: You change the height, but are there constraints? Because it should listen to "constraints" if there are...

Comment: only the messageInputContainerView using constraint. the weird part is only happens on ios14 :( @Larme

Comment: @mimi93 - if you have scrolling disabled on your textView, and you have constraints set properly, you shouldn't need to do any of that. The text view will auto-size its height based on its text.